# Regression testing system which includes compiling the tool, testing and reporting results

Tags: ruby, automation, regression-testing, command-line-tool

I want to set up an automation system to run nightly regression tests for a command line tool on a Linux environment. There are some automation scripts which are written in Ruby, but I'd like a complete system which includes:

1. Build the tool from code base.
2. Run the Ruby automation scripts which I currently have.
3. Generate a test report and send through email.

The nature of this command-tool is low-level which deals with system hardware. Some of the features of the tool could crash the system it is being run on. I want this kind of cases to be reported as well. So, an ideal solution might be to have two computers linked through a network like (like ssh, etc). One system could be for logging and reporting the test results, the other system where the tool is actually run.

Appreciate any ideas you might have.

Comment: What options have you looked at so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) CI server should be able to do what you need. You might have to do some custom work to set up test reports to your liking, but Jenkins is well suited out of the box for the rest of your listed requirements.

As a quick intro I would suggesting checking out some screencasts or other videos on Jenkins - [this talk](http://unethicalblogger.com/2012/10/21/video-continuous-deployment-gerrit-jenkins.html) is an example.